# Guess the twins with something that smells between them

Tags: riddle

Here is a quick riddle.

> We are twins. Between us something smells. Can you guess who we are??

Please place your answers in spoiler tags.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Twins are eyes and nose smells

Answer (score 68):

> Buttcheeks, because.. I don't explain it now :D

Comment: ...exactly where my first thought went ^^.

Comment: So wait, this wasn't the answer?

Answer (score 27):

The word "between" has a couple of meanings - shyos's answer is the usual meaning, but there's also this option:

> Two nostrils - between them, they make up a nose, which smells.

Answer (score 10):

> Two human twins. They both lost their deodorant.